# Bokeh is not generating plot and is instead returning an HTML file

Tags: python-3.x, bokeh

I am new to Python and was trying out the Bokeh library. I try to plot a basic line graph and instead of returning the graph I get an ouput HTML file. When I ran the HTML code it looks like the graph does generate. Does anyone have any idea why the show() method is not showing me the chart as expected. I tried this in both Jupyter Notebook as well as Atom and both return the HTML code. I am running Windows 7 as well.

My code:

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.io import output_file , show

x=[1,2,3,4,5]
y=[6,7,8,9,10]

output_file("test1.html")
f=figure()
f.line(x,y)
show(f)
```

Returned HTML file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>

      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>Bokeh Plot</title> 
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-0.13.0.min.css" type="text/css" />
      <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-0.13.0.min.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript">
            Bokeh.set_log_level("info");
        </script>
  </head>
  <body>
   <div class="bk-root" id="d48bbd43-55c8-4727-befa-468754bdb0b5"></div>
   <script type="application/json" id="41bd10a1-5a61-4504-80f1-8c56f40e644b">
          {"c99a857f-320f-48ba-8576-3ef2bd47c6ce":{"roots":{"references":[{"attributes":{},"id":"c17f31c6-ea53-4bda-b425-65e087f9b126","type":"SaveTool"},{"attributes":{},"id":"d5662033-1332-448f-8078-b1b5fc6ebedd","type":"ResetTool"},{"attributes":{"overlay":{"id":"647df24a-7a53-48f7-850b-e99faaf7e12c","type":"BoxAnnotation"}},"id":"2ebb0a9b-1f3e-4e0e-b54c-dab483d9ad1d","type":"BoxZoomTool"},{"attributes":{"active_drag":"auto","active_inspect":"auto","active_multi":null,"active_scroll":"auto","active_tap":"auto","tools":[{"id":"eea39d89-6da1-4401-a6bb-41d0ad5fd1a9","type":"PanTool"},{"id":"dbdcf43e-f6cd-4999-8664-7d4bbeb28b1b","type":"WheelZoomTool"},{"id":"5e93a11e-972b-4ea4-9ebd-e030a0a92bf5","type":"BoxZoomTool"},{"id":"7b78cfe2-aa29-4245-98c3-b8678943be2c","type":"SaveTool"},{"id":"d5662033-1332-448f-8078-b1b5fc6ebedd","type":"ResetTool"},{"id":"3bcc793e-9b7f-42f7-b939-437b29982b6f","type":"HelpTool"}]},"id":"e29112ae-02d0-4dc6-9788-c3bcd084c560","type":"Toolbar"},{"attributes":{},"id":"ee7e7d93-1a3d-4273-ad05-0dae9c2e2608","type":"BasicTicker"},{"attributes":{"data_source":{"id":"7fedd7ce-eb1b-4533-8e35-492e9f4f6723","type":"ColumnDataSource"},"glyph":{"id":"5c2d97f3-520b-4a40-b4a2-41bde9d2dbc6","type":"Line"},"hover_glyph":null,"muted_glyph":null,"nonselection_glyph":{"id":"762d72ea-6726-4767-aed8-9a5abfbd3abf","type":"Line"},"selection_glyph":null,"view":{"id":"d9fbc277-e9f7-409c-a9b7-8362fed1fe82","type":"CDSView"}},"id":"d495f273-35fd-4f1d-a7c7-44cdc6e2043b","type":"GlyphRenderer"},{"attributes":{},"id":"fdf26c70-7fce-4158-800f-62ef31b890ac","type":"ResetTool"},{"attributes":{"bottom_units":"screen","fill_alpha":{"value":0.5},"fill_color":{"value":"lightgrey"},"left_units":"screen","level":"overlay","line_alpha":{"value":1.0},"line_color":{"value":"black"},"line_dash":[4,4],"line_width":{"value":2},"plot":null,"render_mode":"css","right_units":"screen","top_units":"screen"},"id":"56b62953-67f6-43e5-8665-1ae0b33a3587","type":"BoxAnnotation"},{"attributes":{},"id":"f2bb603d-d041-46dc-9149-5d20c78da06e","type":"PanTool"},{"attributes":{"callback":null,"data":{"x":[1,2,3,4,5],"y":[6,7,8,9,10]},"selected":{"id":"7453ce84-2208-4e58-9d06-ddd3ca1708f6","type":"Selection"},"selection_policy":{"id":"601e5c38-1a36-447b-83d5-64411a4833e8","type":"UnionRenderers"}},"id":"21c90c7e-c156-400b-ba70-8b67b31b460c","type":"ColumnDataSource"},{"attributes":{},"id":"7c17ff42-bbc4-4e59-a0b3-eebe55024f05","type":"BasicTicker"},{"attributes":{"active_drag":"auto","active_inspect":"auto","active_multi":null,"active_scroll":"auto","active_tap":"auto","tools":[{"id":"f2bb603d-d041-46dc-9149-5d20c78da06e","type":"PanTool"},{"id":"ad0a537b-c0d3-4808-846f-be215dbd4631","type":"WheelZoomTool"},{"id":"2ebb0a9b-1f3e-4e0e-b54c-dab483d9ad1d","type":"BoxZoomTool"},{"id":"c17f31c6-ea53-4bda-b425-65e087f9b126","type":"SaveTool"},{"id":"fdf26c70-7fce-4158-800f-62ef31b890ac","type":"ResetTool"},{"id":"949b3238-ac22-4ad2-b652-af77d2e455ad","type":"HelpTool"}]},"id":"096653f5-de71-4386-8bb7-0712ad1765ca","type":"Toolbar"},{"attributes":{},"id":"18ee1741-c202-4f4b-b52e-c2cc490b8f6f","type":"BasicTicker"},{"attributes":{"formatter":{"id":"83cded7e-dad6-4fc7-b0f2-761cc4012436","type":"BasicTickFormatter"},"plot":{"id":"4da3e749-cdb4-48ed-8dc6-b78818d8f587","subtype":"Figure","type":"Plot"},"ticker":{"id":"7c17ff42-bbc4-4e59-a0b3-eebe55024f05","type":"BasicTicker"}},"id":"f5b7139e-5848-412b-9e0b-9c60547d3a47","type":"LinearAxis"},{"attributes":{"data_source":{"id":"21c90c7e-c156-400b-ba70-8b67b31b460c","type":"ColumnDataSource"},"glyph":{"id":"58e9f325-f8d1-44cb-9e83-f757a0bd329a","type":"Line"},"hover_glyph":null,"muted_glyph":null,"nonselection_glyph":{"id":"b6c181de-6d18-433b-8bbd-b14169b56eb5","type":"Line"},"selection_glyph":null,"view":{"id":"64bb6a0d-f877-4657-9ade-525ec88605a9","type":"CDSView"}},"id":"f17257ba-4f75-42c7-893b-a4cf0036740b","type":"GlyphRenderer"},{"attributes":{"dimension":1,"plot":{"id":"4da3e749-cdb4-48ed-8dc6-b78818d8f587","subtype":"Figure","type":"Plot"},"ticker":{"id":"7c17ff42-bbc4-4e59-a0b3-eebe55024f05","type":"BasicTicker"}},"id":"448ae753-190a-47b3-b48c-48d42ad5c905","type":"Grid"},{"attributes":{"callback":null},"id":"320a3e54-e61a-45c3-b12e-64c5570e1c82","type":"DataRange1d"},{"attributes":{"plot":{"id":"4da3e749-cdb4-48ed-8dc6-b78818d8f587","subtype":"Figure","type":"Plot"},"ticker":{"id":"ee7e7d93-1a3d-4273-ad05-0dae9c2e2608","type":"BasicTicker"}},"id":"408bec16-a4cc-48b8-a8e8-9753f9815ed4","type":"Grid"},{"attributes":{},"id":"86e986bf-1069-41b3-b75c-db7e68d1b161","type":"LinearScale"},{"attributes":{},"id":"9e7303e6-a33a-4cfd-8a41-23f8c9b4fe8f","type":"LinearScale"},{"attributes":{},"id":"4d5fd9c6-8637-4d02-b775-2411c95a5d06","type":"LinearScale"},{"attributes":{"formatter":{"id":"f2264866-9fec-45b0-b242-5111fcc1c4fb","type":"BasicTickFormatter"},"plot":{"id":"2da75283-6f20-4600-884a-98e59b066e28","subtype":"Figure","type":"Plot"},"ticker":{"id":"69a59dc3-f814-4f87-a39d-e79d8e0c624c","type":"BasicTicker"}},"id":"264bb8f9-c4f8-4f19-959e-25e2f7c2a656","type":"LinearAxis"},{"attributes":{},"id":"3bcc793e-9b7f-42f7-b939-437b29982b6f","type":"HelpTool"},{"attributes":{"dimension":1,"plot":{"id":"2da75283-6f20-4600-884a-98e59b066e28","subtype":"Figure","type":"Plot"},"ticker":{"id":"69a59dc3-f814-4f87-a39d-e79d8e0c624c","type":"BasicTicker"}},"id":"f496d5a9-0ee6-460b-9016-3fa5c19a56a7","type":"Grid"},{"attributes":{},"id":"1b240c0f-07b2-4113-a8a8-a4efc1583fdd","type":"BasicTickFormatter"},{"attributes":{},"id":"69a59dc3-f814-4f87-a39d-e79d8e0c624c","type":"BasicTicker"},{"attributes":{"source":{"id":"7fedd7ce-eb1b-4533-8e35-492e9f4f6723","type":"ColumnDataSource"}},"id":"d9fbc277-e9f7-409c-a9b7-8362fed1fe82","type":"CDSView"},{"attributes":{"callback":null},"id":"98a9bfe3-e787-4432-af9d-0f3f9f086166","type":"DataRange1d"},{"attributes":{},"id":"7453ce84-2208-4e58-9d06-ddd3ca1708f6","type":"Selection"},{"attributes":{"plot":{"id":"2da75283-6f20-4600-884a-98e59b066e28","subtype":"Figure","type":"Plot"},"ticker":{"id":"18ee1741-c202-4f4b-b52e-c2cc490b8f6f","type":"BasicTicker"}},"id":"937c1124-b157-4eca-a0b3-75f6ef2dda90","type":"Grid"},{"attributes":{"callback":null},"id":"95e74f2e-df09-4945-a76e-c185eea3d4df","type":"DataRange1d"},{"attributes":{"formatter":{"id":"2030a3a4-7747-427a-a1dd-ffc3901ee9be","type":"BasicTickFormatter"},"plot":{"id":"4da3e749-cdb4-48ed-8dc6-b78818d8f587","subtype":"Figure","type":"Plot"},"ticker":{"id":"ee7e7d93-1a3d-4273-ad05-0dae9c2e2608","type":"BasicTicker"}},"id":"90583a87-4ad1-402c-aa3c-1a3c661e7406","type":"LinearAxis"},{"attributes":{"source":{"id":"7f04e4d5-b03b-4ebb-a89d-f65cbb91b729","type":"ColumnDataSource"}},"id":"58980905-7efb-4a11-8de9-9b10e9b1d1c8","type":"CDSView"},{"attributes":{"callback":null,"data":{"x":[3,7.5,10],"y":[3,6,9]},"selected":{"id":"668b3eb0-b6de-4fc7-ae7b-d1a7ce923009","type":"Selection"},"selection_policy":{"id":"4dc9ce99-d94b-4fbd-9ed2-ef8bb292be8b","type":"UnionRenderers"}},"id":"7f04e4d5-b03b-4ebb-a89d-f65cbb91b729","type":"ColumnDataSource"},{"attributes":{"line_alpha":0.1,"line_color":"#1f77b4","x":{"field":"x"},"y":{"field":"y"}},"id":"762d72ea-6726-4767-aed8-9a5abfbd3abf","type":"Line"},{"attributes":{},"id":"5ec88388-4913-436f-b8a6-cfd6d391154c","type":"BasicTickFormatter"},{"attributes":{},"id":"eea39d89-6da1-4401-a6bb-41d0ad5fd1a9","type":"PanTool"},{"attributes":{"callback":null},"id":"d9d21cdf-f19b-4f95-98ba-ef43d9aec5a7","type":"DataRange1d"},{"attributes":{},"id":"ad0a537b-c0d3-4808-846f-be215dbd4631","type":"WheelZoomTool"},{"attributes":{"formatter":{"id":"1b240c0f-07b2-4113-a8a8-a4efc1583fdd","type":"BasicTickFormatter"},"plot":{"id":"2da75283-6f20-4600-884a-98e59b066e28","subtype":"Figure","type":"Plot"},"ticker":{"id":"18ee1741-c202-4f4b-b52e-c2cc490b8f6f","type":"BasicTicker"}},"id":"8977dc31-58c8-4dda-95bc-70199558a319","type":"LinearAxis"},{"attributes":{},"id":"2030a3a4-7747-427a-a1dd-ffc3901ee9be","type":"BasicTickFormatter"},{"attributes":{},"id":"541dc82f-bd18-4993-adff-060c1167d6ab","type":"Selection"},{"attributes":{},"id":"4dc9ce99-d94b-4fbd-9ed2-ef8bb292be8b","type":"UnionRenderers"},{"attributes":{},"id":"83cded7e-dad6-4fc7-b0f2-761cc4012436","type":"BasicTickFormatter"},{"attributes":{"bottom_units":"screen","fill_alpha":{"value":0.5},"fill_color":{"value":"lightgrey"},"left_units":"screen","level":"overlay","line_alpha":{"value":1.0},"line_color":{"value":"black"},"line_dash":[4,4],"line_width":{"value":2},"plot":null,"render_mode":"css","right_units":"screen","top_units":"screen"},"id":"647df24a-7a53-48f7-850b-e99faaf7e12c","type":"BoxAnnotation"},{"attributes":{},"id":"949b3238-ac22-4ad2-b652-af77d2e455ad","type":"HelpTool"},{"attributes":{"formatter":{"id":"5ec88388-4913-436f-b8a6-cfd6d391154c","type":"BasicTickFormatter"},"plot":{"id":"635f8152-f2d6-4568-ae68-2973f310eaf8","subtype":"Figure","type":"Plot"},"ticker":{"id":"164ee759-2971-4dd9-ac18-35cdb02fca0e","type":"BasicTicker"}},"id":"f1e22f73-d0fc-46b4-a3b4-b264cf417d4a","type":"LinearAxis"},{"attributes":{"callback":null},"id":"0eb66654-fd86-43a2-8b94-2f345c420dec","type":"DataRange1d"},{"attributes":{},"id":"dbdcf43e-f6cd-4999-8664-7d4bbeb28b1b","type":"WheelZoomTool"},{"attributes":{"callback":null},"id":"66ecc1d0-d899-41cd-b791-13176cd24a81","type":"DataRange1d"},{"attributes":{},"id":"26a46564-9ff5-4fdb-987a-a2119540680b","type":"LinearScale"},{"attributes":{"formatter":{"id":"e87b8867-6df4-4f58-a378-25f653b25bf6","type":"BasicTickFormatter"},"plot":{"id":"635f8152-f2d6-4568-ae68-2973f310eaf8","subtype":"Figure","type":"Plot"},"ticker":{"id":"cfd25d7d-feea-4647-911d-6a5605dc3d71","type":"BasicTicker"}},"id":"474d496d-aa15-4fe3-b163-0a629270845f","type":"LinearAxis"},{"attributes":{"below":[{"id":"90583a87-4ad1-402c-aa3c-1a3c661e7406","type":"LinearAxis"}],"left":[{"id":"f5b7139e-5848-412b-9e0b-9c60547d3a47","type":"LinearAxis"}],"renderers":[{"id":"90583a87-4ad1-402c-aa3c-1a3c661e7406","type":"LinearAxis"},{"id":"408bec16-a4cc-48b8-a8e8-9753f9815ed4","type":"Grid"},{"id":"f5b7139e-5848-412b-9e0b-9c60547d3a47","type":"LinearAxis"},{"id":"448ae753-190a-47b3-b48c-48d42ad5c905","type":"Grid"},{"id":"647df24a-7a53-48f7-850b-e99faaf7e12c","type":"BoxAnnotation"},{"id":"d495f273-35fd-4f1d-a7c7-44cdc6e2043b","type":"GlyphRenderer"}],"title":{"id":"d4c3a0d9-1a75-4bf7-a107-1d30bf785c76","type":"Title"},"toolbar":{"id":"096653f5-de71-4386-8bb7-0712ad1765ca","type":"Toolbar"},"x_range":{"id":"95e74f2e-df09-4945-a76e-c185eea3d4df","type":"DataRange1d"},"x_scale":{"id":"c561783a-f07e-44c4-8bce-04e3a3363ae6","type":"LinearScale"},"y_range":{"id":"0eb66654-fd86-43a2-8b94-2f345c420dec","type":"DataRange1d"},"y_scale":{"id":"4d5fd9c6-8637-4d02-b775-2411c95a5d06","type":"LinearScale"}},"id":"4da3e749-cdb4-48ed-8dc6-b78818d8f587","subtype":"Figure","type":"Plot"},{"attributes":{},"id":"f95a9d96-e1ac-4ce5-bc22-36cf2f38f282","type":"LinearScale"},{"attributes":{"line_color":"#1f77b4","x":{"field":"x"},"y":{"field":"y"}},"id":"5c2d97f3-520b-4a40-b4a2-41bde9d2dbc6","type":"Line"},{"attributes":{"active_drag":"auto","active_inspect":"auto","active_multi":null,"active_scroll":"auto","active_tap":"auto","tools":[{"id":"568ebe47-1b17-4fc7-8859-72a1e4b19c03","type":"PanTool"},{"id":"e1d4052b-2921-4d77-ad94-6918560aa1ba","type":"WheelZoomTool"},{"id":"0854e626-a869-4df9-8767-e630ecd58a96","type":"BoxZoomTool"},{"id":"110fc368-ca75-4219-8f15-890fcdb2f36b","type":"SaveTool"},{"id":"885ac673-f730-49e8-813f-64fd64eaf473","type":"ResetTool"},{"id":"f80496c0-9c80-4a80-8f2f-da85474351ca","type":"HelpTool"}]},"id":"f941560f-8e6b-451c-9eb8-adefc4eb40ab","type":"Toolbar"},{"attributes":{"below":[{"id":"f1e22f73-d0fc-46b4-a3b4-b264cf417d4a","type":"LinearAxis"}],"left":[{"id":"474d496d-aa15-4fe3-b163-0a629270845f","type":"LinearAxis"}],"renderers":[{"id":"f1e22f73-d0fc-46b4-a3b4-b264cf417d4a","type":"LinearAxis"},{"id":"76ad232d-7081-49f8-aed9-647e4230aca4","type":"Grid"},{"id":"474d496d-aa15-4fe3-b163-0a629270845f","type":"LinearAxis"},{"id":"c3bc6c16-6356-43da-9153-d0f6463dc876","type":"Grid"},{"id":"9f88dd88-dbad-4b5b-ae2d-b1d2d8c36a15","type":"BoxAnnotation"},{"id":"e8a9236a-3159-4555-ab32-5a71f98315fe","type":"GlyphRenderer"}],"title":{"id":"398834ce-a8d9-46e0-923e-ab71eb6e8aa8","type":"Title"},"toolbar":{"id":"f941560f-8e6b-451c-9eb8-adefc4eb40ab","type":"Toolbar"},"x_range":{"id":"320a3e54-e61a-45c3-b12e-64c5570e1c82","type":"DataRange1d"},"x_scale":{"id":"26a46564-9ff5-4fdb-987a-a2119540680b","type":"LinearScale"},"y_range":{"id":"66ecc1d0-d899-41cd-b791-13176cd24a81","type":"DataRange1d"},"y_scale":{"id":"f95a9d96-e1ac-4ce5-bc22-36cf2f38f282","type":"LinearScale"}},"id":"635f8152-f2d6-4568-ae68-2973f310eaf8","subtype":"Figure","type":"Plot"},{"attributes":{"plot":{"id":"635f8152-f2d6-4568-ae68-2973f310eaf8","subtype":"Figure","type":"Plot"},"ticker":{"id":"164ee759-2971-4dd9-ac18-35cdb02fca0e","type":"BasicTicker"}},"id":"76ad232d-7081-49f8-aed9-647e4230aca4","type":"Grid"},{"attributes":{},"id":"164ee759-2971-4dd9-ac18-35cdb02fca0e","type":"BasicTicker"},{"attributes":{"callback":null,"data":{"x":[1,2,3,4,5],"y":[6,7,8,9,10]},"selected":{"id":"541dc82f-bd18-4993-adff-060c1167d6ab","type":"Selection"},"selection_policy":{"id":"ad391a37-ff57-4e0e-a32f-1fc91db098fc","type":"UnionRenderers"}},"id":"7fedd7ce-eb1b-4533-8e35-492e9f4f6723","type":"ColumnDataSource"},{"attributes":{"dimension":1,"plot":{"id":"635f8152-f2d6-4568-ae68-2973f310eaf8","subtype":"Figure","type":"Plot"},"ticker":{"id":"cfd25d7d-feea-4647-911d-6a5605dc3d71","type":"BasicTicker"}},"id":"c3bc6c16-6356-43da-9153-d0f6463dc876","type":"Grid"},{"attributes":{},"id":"cfd25d7d-feea-4647-911d-6a5605dc3d71","type":"BasicTicker"},{"attributes":{},"id":"c561783a-f07e-44c4-8bce-04e3a3363ae6","type":"LinearScale"},{"attributes":{},"id":"ad391a37-ff57-4e0e-a32f-1fc91db098fc","type":"UnionRenderers"},{"attributes":{"plot":null,"text":""},"id":"398834ce-a8d9-46e0-923e-ab71eb6e8aa8","type":"Title"},{"attributes":{},"id":"568ebe47-1b17-4fc7-8859-72a1e4b19c03","type":"PanTool"},{"attributes":{},"id":"e1d4052b-2921-4d77-ad94-6918560aa1ba","type":"WheelZoomTool"},{"attributes":{"overlay":{"id":"9f88dd88-dbad-4b5b-ae2d-b1d2d8c36a15","type":"BoxAnnotation"}},"id":"0854e626-a869-4df9-8767-e630ecd58a96","type":"BoxZoomTool"},{"attributes":{},"id":"110fc368-ca75-4219-8f15-890fcdb2f36b","type":"SaveTool"},{"attributes":{},"id":"885ac673-f730-49e8-813f-64fd64eaf473","type":"ResetTool"},{"attributes":{},"id":"f80496c0-9c80-4a80-8f2f-da85474351ca","type":"HelpTool"},{"attributes":{"bottom_units":"screen","fill_alpha":{"value":0.5},"fill_color":{"value":"lightgrey"},"left_units":"screen","level":"overlay","line_alpha":{"value":1.0},"line_color":{"value":"black"},"line_dash":[4,4],"line_width":{"value":2},"plot":null,"render_mode":"css","right_units":"screen","top_units":"screen"},"id":"9f88dd88-dbad-4b5b-ae2d-b1d2d8c36a15","type":"BoxAnnotation"},{"attributes":{"fill_alpha":{"value":0.1},"fill_color":{"value":"#1f77b4"},"line_alpha":{"value":0.1},"line_color":{"value":"#1f77b4"},"x":{"field":"x"},"y":{"field":"y"}},"id":"8f473bf9-6ee0-4c0f-b549-b2f0b00fa17f","type":"Triangle"},{"attributes":{"line_color":"#1f77b4","x":{"field":"x"},"y":{"field":"y"}},"id":"58e9f325-f8d1-44cb-9e83-f757a0bd329a","type":"Line"},{"attributes":{"line_alpha":0.1,"line_color":"#1f77b4","x":{"field":"x"},"y":{"field":"y"}},"id":"b6c181de-6d18-433b-8bbd-b14169b56eb5","type":"Line"},{"attributes":{},"id":"668b3eb0-b6de-4fc7-ae7b-d1a7ce923009","type":"Selection"},{"attributes":{"plot":null,"text":""},"id":"d4c3a0d9-1a75-4bf7-a107-1d30bf785c76","type":"Title"},{"attributes":{},"id":"e87b8867-6df4-4f58-a378-25f653b25bf6","type":"BasicTickFormatter"},{"attributes":{},"id":"7b78cfe2-aa29-4245-98c3-b8678943be2c","type":"SaveTool"},{"attributes":{},"id":"601e5c38-1a36-447b-83d5-64411a4833e8","type":"UnionRenderers"},{"attributes":{"data_source":{"id":"7f04e4d5-b03b-4ebb-a89d-f65cbb91b729","type":"ColumnDataSource"},"glyph":{"id":"cda92757-3dcd-42cb-95b9-392e57684258","type":"Triangle"},"hover_glyph":null,"muted_glyph":null,"nonselection_glyph":{"id":"8f473bf9-6ee0-4c0f-b549-b2f0b00fa17f","type":"Triangle"},"selection_glyph":null,"view":{"id":"58980905-7efb-4a11-8de9-9b10e9b1d1c8","type":"CDSView"}},"id":"e8a9236a-3159-4555-ab32-5a71f98315fe","type":"GlyphRenderer"},{"attributes":{"below":[{"id":"8977dc31-58c8-4dda-95bc-70199558a319","type":"LinearAxis"}],"left":[{"id":"264bb8f9-c4f8-4f19-959e-25e2f7c2a656","type":"LinearAxis"}],"renderers":[{"id":"8977dc31-58c8-4dda-95bc-70199558a319","type":"LinearAxis"},{"id":"937c1124-b157-4eca-a0b3-75f6ef2dda90","type":"Grid"},{"id":"264bb8f9-c4f8-4f19-959e-25e2f7c2a656","type":"LinearAxis"},{"id":"f496d5a9-0ee6-460b-9016-3fa5c19a56a7","type":"Grid"},{"id":"56b62953-67f6-43e5-8665-1ae0b33a3587","type":"BoxAnnotation"},{"id":"f17257ba-4f75-42c7-893b-a4cf0036740b","type":"GlyphRenderer"}],"title":{"id":"af901232-8aa2-488c-932c-c8e5dda2750d","type":"Title"},"toolbar":{"id":"e29112ae-02d0-4dc6-9788-c3bcd084c560","type":"Toolbar"},"x_range":{"id":"98a9bfe3-e787-4432-af9d-0f3f9f086166","type":"DataRange1d"},"x_scale":{"id":"86e986bf-1069-41b3-b75c-db7e68d1b161","type":"LinearScale"},"y_range":{"id":"d9d21cdf-f19b-4f95-98ba-ef43d9aec5a7","type":"DataRange1d"},"y_scale":{"id":"9e7303e6-a33a-4cfd-8a41-23f8c9b4fe8f","type":"LinearScale"}},"id":"2da75283-6f20-4600-884a-98e59b066e28","subtype":"Figure","type":"Plot"},{"attributes":{"overlay":{"id":"56b62953-67f6-43e5-8665-1ae0b33a3587","type":"BoxAnnotation"}},"id":"5e93a11e-972b-4ea4-9ebd-e030a0a92bf5","type":"BoxZoomTool"},{"attributes":{"plot":null,"text":""},"id":"af901232-8aa2-488c-932c-c8e5dda2750d","type":"Title"},{"attributes":{"fill_color":{"value":"#1f77b4"},"line_color":{"value":"#1f77b4"},"x":{"field":"x"},"y":{"field":"y"}},"id":"cda92757-3dcd-42cb-95b9-392e57684258","type":"Triangle"},{"attributes":{"source":{"id":"21c90c7e-c156-400b-ba70-8b67b31b460c","type":"ColumnDataSource"}},"id":"64bb6a0d-f877-4657-9ade-525ec88605a9","type":"CDSView"},{"attributes":{},"id":"f2264866-9fec-45b0-b242-5111fcc1c4fb","type":"BasicTickFormatter"}],"root_ids":["635f8152-f2d6-4568-ae68-2973f310eaf8","2da75283-6f20-4600-884a-98e59b066e28","4da3e749-cdb4-48ed-8dc6-b78818d8f587"]},"title":"Bokeh Application","version":"0.13.0"}}
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
          (function() {
            var fn = function() {
              Bokeh.safely(function() {
                (function(root) {
                  function embed_document(root) {

                  var docs_json = document.getElementById('41bd10a1-5a61-4504-80f1-8c56f40e644b').textContent;
                  var render_items = [{"docid":"c99a857f-320f-48ba-8576-3ef2bd47c6ce","roots":{"4da3e749-cdb4-48ed-8dc6-b78818d8f587":"d48bbd43-55c8-4727-befa-468754bdb0b5"}}];
                  root.Bokeh.embed.embed_items(docs_json, render_items);

                  }
                  if (root.Bokeh !== undefined) {
                    embed_document(root);
                  } else {
                    var attempts = 0;
                    var timer = setInterval(function(root) {
                      if (root.Bokeh !== undefined) {
                        embed_document(root);
                        clearInterval(timer);
                      }
                      attempts++;
                      if (attempts > 100) {
                        console.log("Bokeh: ERROR: Unable to run BokehJS code because BokehJS library is missing")
                        clearInterval(timer);
                      }
                    }, 10, root)
                  }
                })(window);
              });
            };
            if (document.readyState != "loading") fn();
            else document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", fn);
          })();
        </script>

  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: It's always going to return an HTML file considering you're calling `output_file("test1.html")`

Comment: I thought it would show the graph in a new tab in the browser? It doesn't do that at all.

Comment: As mentioned, `show` always saves an HTML file. It then tries to open that file in a new tab, but in that regard, `show`  is only a very thin wrapper around the built-in Python standard library `webbrowser` module. If it's not opening a new tab then it is some configuration issue on your system that is preventing Python itself from raising a browser window.

Comment: Also, Bokeh plots *are* HTML and JavaScript. Bokeh is designed explicitly for interactive visualization *in the browser*, that is its purpose. Are you expecting a PNG or something? You have to explicitly export plots to get those: https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/export.html

Comment: Got it. Thanks!

Comment: I should clarify: `show` without `output_file` will always save a file. `show` with `output_notebook` will display plots inline in the notebook. All of the example notebooks demonstrate this.

Answer (score 0):

Yes that will happen but is easy to resolve :

right click the (output html file) in  working folder ---> hover over open with----> choose default program---> click on always open with (google chrome)

Now the next time you run your code plot will open up in chrome instead of .html file in notepad